# Can I reuse the Input withing params in a gnls?

Tags: r, nlme

a question I assume to know the anser, but none could tell me why. To make it short, I employ an example from Pinheiro & Bates (2000).

```
library(nlme)
fm1Dial.gnls <- gnls(rate ~ SSasympOff(pressure, Asym, lrc, c0),
                     data = Dialyzer, 
                     params = list(Asym + lrc ~ QB, c0 ~ 1),
                     start = c(53.6, 8.6, 0.51, -0.26, 0.225) )
summary(fm1Dial.gnls)
```

I can find `pressure` not among the coefficients. 
To obtain an coefficient for it, would it be legal to use `pressure` within `params` or would I then use a parameter to explain itself? Could this in any way be seen as a hint how `pressure` affects `rate`?

```
fm2Dial.gnls <- gnls( rate ~ SSasympOff(pressure, Asym, lrc, c0),
                      data = Dialyzer, 
                      params = list(Asym + lrc ~ pressure, c0 ~ 1),
                      start = c(53.6, 8.6, 0.51, -0.26, 0.225) )
summary(fm2Dial.gnls)
```

The data is just as an example and has no further meaning.
For any answer I would be very grateful.

Comment: I've voted to close and migrate to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), as I think the question is more about construction and interpretation of models than about programming.  My guess is that what you want to do is mathematically legal but probably not sensible.

Comment: Thank you. I will open it there :)